# using pandas.DataFrame.to_excel without creating a new sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know if there is a way to paste a dataframe in excel using pandas.DataFrame.to_excel and keep the data in an existing sheet without erasing the existing data in there. I need to do that because there are many dataframes being created from a loop, so I need to storage this information together appending the content. As follows some code:

```
    lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

    with pd.ExcelWriter('teste.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
            pd.DataFrame(lista).to_excel(writer,  header=False, index=False, startrow=3, startcol=1, 
            sheet_name="Hoja1")
```

The result is very annoying because even though I pass "Hoja1" as the sheet_name it ends up creating another sheet with a similar name.

Comment: append: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Thanks for help me out! As you can see in my code I'm already using mode="a" for appending in the same sheet, but for some reason it creates another one.